# Laravel with() method additional constraints while fetching child

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called `vehicles` that has a one to many relationship with the table called `fuel_entries`. How do I obtain `fuel_entries` data that has been added over the course of two specific days when I fetch the `vehicle` model?

Consider the scenario where I want all vehicles with fuel entries, but I only want fuel entries added between date `x` to `y`, not all of them.

```
 $vehicles = Vehicle::with('fuels')->get();
```

Comment: _I only want the most recent three days'_ so order by created_at column in descending order pick the top 3?

Comment: Check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads; you can add logic to your `with()` function to constrain the loaded records, something like `Vehicle::with(['fuels' => function ($subQuery) { // limit to last 3 days }])->get()`

Comment: Thank you, I've just figured it out. @TimLewis

Comment: Excellent  If you'd like, you may add your solution as an answer in the section below if you think others can benefit from the information. If not, you may delete this question, or leave it as is. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::withSum(['fuels' => fn($query) => $query->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])],'quantity')
->withCount(['fuels' => function ($query) use ($start,$end) {
    $query->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end]);
}])
->withSum(
    ['fuels' => fn($query) => $query->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])],'cost'
)
->withMax(
    ['fuels' => fn($query) => $query->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])],'date'
)->get();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).